# capturar valor de una campo de la tabla

Tags: php

Hola chico llevo tiempo dando le vuelta a esta situación.
Lo que tengo es una pagina PHP para mostrar una tabla cargada de una base de datos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

    <body>
    <p>Buscar un registro</p>
    
    <br>
    <form action="PagPrincipal.php" method="post">
    
     <label Buscar: ><input type="text" name="buscar"></label>
     <br>
     <br>
     <input type="submit" name="Buscar" value="Buscar">
     <br>
     <br>
     <input type="button" value="Insertar" onClick="location.href = 'Insertar.php' ">
     <br>
     <br>
     
    </form>
    
    <?php
    
  
    require 'cont_func.php';
  
   if (empty($_POST['buscar'])) {
       MostrarTabla();
   }
    
    
    else if (isset($_POST['Buscar'])) {
        $busqueda = $_POST['buscar'];
        
        buscarEnNombreArt($busqueda);
        
    }
    
 ?>
 
 
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Tengo otra pagina cont_funcc.php que contiene todas la funciones.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_nombre = "pruebas";
$db_usuario = "root";
$db_contra = "";
$cod = "";
$resultado;

function MostrarTabla()
{
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    global $cod;
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Error en la conexion";
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
    
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos";
    
    $ejecucionConsulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
    
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($ejecucionConsulta)) {
        
        echo "<table><tr><td>";
         echo "<a name = 'eliminar' href='cont_funcc.php?id=" . $fila[0] . "'>enlace</a>,</td><td>";
        
        echo $fila[0], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[1], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[2], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[3], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[4], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[5], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[6], "</td></tr></table>";
    }
    
    mysqli_close($conexion);
   
}

function buscarEnNombreArt($busqueda)
{
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion a la base de datos';
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die('No se encuentra la tabla');
    
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE NombreArt LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
    
    $ejecutarConsulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($ejecutarConsulta)) {
        
        echo "<table><tr><td>";
        echo $fila[0], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[1], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[2], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[3], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[4], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[5], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[6], "</td></tr></table>";
    }
}

function insertar()
{
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    global $resultado;
    $cod = $_POST['codigo'];
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion a la base de datos';
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die('No se encuentra la tabla');
    
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO productos (Codigo , Fecha , Importado , NombreArt , PaisOrigen , Precio , Seccion) VALUES ('AR24', '2002-12-12' , 'Si', 'Calcetines' , 'Franca' , 5.25 , 'Confeccion');";
    $consulta1 = "INSERT INTO productos (Codigo) VALUES ('$cod')";
    
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta1);
    
    // header("Location: http://localhost/ConexionBD_Modo_Procedimiento/Busqueda_Resultado_Misma_Pagina/Insertar.php");
    if ($resultado) {
        echo "insertado con exito";
    } else {
        echo "No insertado";
    }
    header("Refresh:3; url=Insertar.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['insertar'])) {
    insertar();
}

function eliminar($cod)
{
    
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    global $resultado;
    $cod = $_POST['codigo'];
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion a la base de datos';
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die('No se encuentra la tabla');
    
    $consulta1 = "DELETE * FROM productos WHERE Codigo = '$cod' ";
    
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta1);
    
    if ($consulta1) {
        echo "eliminado con exito";
    } else {
        echo "No se ha eliminado";
    }
}




echo $cod;

?>


</body>
</html>
```

para la función  eliminar  tengo que pasar le la $fila[0] de la función 
  mostrar tabla(). como lo hago?? Es decir le tengo que pasar el  código del producto que se guarda en $fila[0]

Tal como lo tengo ahora es para que se envié a la misma pagina  la variable id con el valor de fila[0] y no me vale

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas chequear si el parametro id esta presente, y si lo esta, ejecutas tu funcion asi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_nombre = "pruebas";
$db_usuario = "root";
$db_contra = "";
$cod = "";
$resultado;

if (isset($_GET['id']) {
    eliminar($_GET['id']);
}

function MostrarTabla()
{
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    global $cod;
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Error en la conexion";
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
    
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos";
    
    $ejecucionConsulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
    
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($ejecucionConsulta)) {
        
        echo "<table><tr><td>";
         echo "<a name = 'eliminar' href='cont_funcc.php?id=" . $fila[0] . "'>enlace</a>,</td><td>";
        
        echo $fila[0], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[1], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[2], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[3], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[4], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[5], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[6], "</td></tr></table>";
    }
    
    mysqli_close($conexion);
   
}

function buscarEnNombreArt($busqueda)
{
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion a la base de datos';
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die('No se encuentra la tabla');
    
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE NombreArt LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
    
    $ejecutarConsulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($ejecutarConsulta)) {
        
        echo "<table><tr><td>";
        echo $fila[0], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[1], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[2], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[3], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[4], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[5], "</td><td>";
        echo $fila[6], "</td></tr></table>";
    }
}

function insertar()
{
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    global $resultado;
    $cod = $_POST['codigo'];
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion a la base de datos';
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die('No se encuentra la tabla');
    
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO productos (Codigo , Fecha , Importado , NombreArt , PaisOrigen , Precio , Seccion) VALUES ('AR24', '2002-12-12' , 'Si', 'Calcetines' , 'Franca' , 5.25 , 'Confeccion');";
    $consulta1 = "INSERT INTO productos (Codigo) VALUES ('$cod')";
    
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta1);
    
    // header("Location: http://localhost/ConexionBD_Modo_Procedimiento/Busqueda_Resultado_Misma_Pagina/Insertar.php");
    if ($resultado) {
        echo "insertado con exito";
    } else {
        echo "No insertado";
    }
    header("Refresh:3; url=Insertar.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['insertar'])) {
    insertar();
}

function eliminar($cod)
{
    
    global $db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre;
    global $resultado;
    $cod = $_POST['codigo'];
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);
    
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion a la base de datos';
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die('No se encuentra la tabla');
    
    $consulta1 = "DELETE * FROM productos WHERE Codigo = '$cod' ";
    
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta1);
    
    if ($consulta1) {
        echo "eliminado con exito";
    } else {
        echo "No se ha eliminado";
    }
}




echo $cod;

?>


</body>
</html>
```